# Why the MobileNetV2 is faster than MobileNetV1 only at mobile device?

Tags: tensorflow, mobile, gpu

I am studying about Google's brandnew `MobileNetV2` architecture.

During studying, I've read this string at Tensorflow model zoo Github

'For example Mobilenet V2 is faster on mobile devices than Mobilenet V1, but is slightly slower on desktop GPU.'

So, my question is,

How that could be possible? I really want to know why.

Comment: It was probably designed and tuned with a mobile experience in mind.

Comment: Thanks! But, is there any EXACT explaination about that?? :( Not probably

Comment: You can read the paper about [MobileNetV2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.04381). And here is the [pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.04381.pdf).

Comment: I have already read paper, but there is no description about the reasons. I'm not a dude bro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08469v1 :

"However, MobileNet V2 uses **depthwise separable convolutions which are not directly supported in GPU firmware** (the cuDNN library). Therefore, MobileNet V2 tends to be slower than ResNet18 in most experimental setups. Note that the same issue disqualifies usage of the DenseNet architecture [12], since it requires efficient convolution over a non-contiguous tensor, which is still not supported in cuDNN."

Comment: Thank you. really understandable for me :)

Comment: But V1 is also use the depthwise separable convolutions.

Comment: @XiaXuehai, two factors may to contribute to this: 1) MobileNetV1 has 13 depthwise separable convolution whereas MobileNetV2 has got 17 of them. 2) MobileNetV1 goes through its depthwise convolution with 64/12/256/512/1024 channels whereas MobilNetV2 uses 96/192/384/768/1536 channels. Thus MobileNetV2 may be slower on GPU than V1. Following this raisonning, on CPU, MobileNetV2 would be quicker than V1 thanks to the channel reduction (bottleneck). In V2, channels number in the 1x1 conv are divided by 6. In V2, only the depthwise convolution use this high number of channels, not the 1x1 conv.

Comment: @M.Riché Is this still the case with newer cuDNN versions? Has anyone benchmarked V1 vs V2 recently?

Answer (score 0):

From their published paper at [MobileNetV2: Inverted Residuals and Linear Bottlenecks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.04381.pdf),

under subtopic number 5: Implementation Notes, 5.1. Memory efficient inference;

> The inverted residual bottleneck layers allow a particularly
>   memory efficient implementation which is very
>   important for mobile applications. (and more in paper)

According to TensorFlow team, it's optimized smaller in size can also be used as TF Lite. As far as we know TF Lite is indeed for mobile use. It's much slower on desktop GPU probably V2 has more conv layers compared to V1 which make sense if the training tooks more times to finish. For now, we didn't do the training and inferencing of data on mobile because of computational speed hunger which lead to power hunger as well.

Hope I answer the question.